# How can i resolve context initialization failed?

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-mvc, javabeans

Getting an exception when deploying the code.I tried with many possibilities but couldn't resolve this issue. Is this happening because of maven dependencies? Some one can help me to get out of from this issue.

```
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationStatusLogDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.vmware.vrack.vrm.core.configuration.dao.ConfigurationStatusLogDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [vrm-postgre-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
          org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
```

Below code is context.xml file which this error says,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans profile="default"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.security.auth.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.security.audit.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.core.property.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.core.configuration.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.core.vcenter.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.core.physical</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.prm.**.*</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.event</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.core.bundlemgmt</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.core.psc</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.lcm.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.security.password.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.pmm.entity</value>
                <value>com.vmware.vrack.vrm.security.profile.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <!--<prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver.className}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.connections.initialsize}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="70" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't get you that what your are saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main cause of your error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
```

So you have to add `hibernate-<version>.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: @jeans i'll try to add this jar to my project.

Comment: @Jeans this is not working, Is this related to spring issue? it seems like that? do u have any idea about this?